# Convert and concatenate

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, string-concatenation

My input is month and year in integer.

- **month  year**
- 8            2011
- 9            2012
- 10           2012

I want the output as month and year concatenated as month name and year.

- mon_yr
- August 2011
- September 2012
- October 2012

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Use the DateName function to find the month_name, But that function requires a date value as input, so converting the month number to a date in the inside query..

```
declare @month int=3
declare @year int=2012

Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , @month , 0 ) - 1 )
                                           +' '+cast( @year as char(4))
```

**result**:

```
March 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
declare @month int
declare @year int

select @month = 3
select @year = 2012

select datename(month , dateadd(mm, @month, '20120101')) + ' ' + cast(@year as char(4))
```